# Can I stop my HTML page from loading until after my Facebook login status script has run?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK to enforce that users who access my site must be logged into Facebook. I'm using the function *StatusChangeCallback* to redirect visitors to a Facebook login page if they aren't logged into Facebook. I have copied a snippet of my script below, which is in the Head tag of my web page.

This works fine, except that I notice that my page loads momentarily before the script redirects the visitors to a login page. That means that visitors can click the "Stop" button and bypass this redirect functionality.

**Is there a way to prevent the page from loading until after my Facebook login script has completed?**

```
    <script>
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      //Continue loading the page 
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      window.location.href = "facebook.html";
    } else {
      window.location.href = "facebook.html";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but if you intend users to not see your page till they've logged in, any client side solution is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide the page using css

```
html { visibility:hidden; }
```

And then set it to visible after your script has ran with javascript/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! I added document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.visibility = "visible" after the code if (response.status === 'connected'), and I'm all set. Thanks!!! I spent days trying to come up with a solution that didn't involve something too complex, this was so simple!

Comment: No problem :) Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Can you place the checking function on a page that they are coming from? Maybe the link that they press to get there?

Answer (score 0):

How important is it to you that people are logged in before they see the content? If 'very' important, you should know that most everything relying on JS alone will be circumventable.

For instance, this seems like it might work (presuming no need-to-be-logged-in content is on your landing page):

```
...
if (response.status === 'connected') {
   // jQuery for brevity
   $('#your-wrapper').load('path/to/authenticated/content.html');
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
   window.location.href = "facebook.html";
} ...
```

but there's nothing to stop a user with a browser console from seeing that URL and visiting it directly.

I'm assuming FB sends you some sort of token back within `response`. You could add that to your ajaxy content load as a sort of 'key' but again, easy to fake from the browser without an additional layer of server side authentication.

You might get an extra 1/2 security point by making `'path/to/authenticated/content.html'` only respond to requests from the same server by using old Apache "Anti-hotlinking" tricks. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images

Comment: I originally went down this path and created a bunch of pages and redirected pages (e.g., content.php and content1.php) but yes, that meant that anyone could just bypass this by going to content1.php.

The information on my website isn't sensitive by any means; I mostly wanted the facebook login because I have a couple of forms to collect information and it looks like someone ran a script to populate my "database" (read: json file) with a bunch of advertisements for viagra.

I used Lakutis' suggestion above and I think that provides just enough befuddlement for my needs.

Comment: Not with the Apache trick, I don't think. But yeah, this is all slippery path business.